# Safari Menu bug, jumping around on hover?

Tags: jquery, css

Been trying to diagnose this bug... I've narrowed it down to a conflict between the "royal slider" plugin I'm using. The menu up top seems to start jumping only in Safari. When you hover over the menu it just goes nuts

I've put a SCREENR grab together so you can see.
http://www.screenr.com/CB2H

The URL is here:
http://goo.gl/UdWiw

I've looked through the CSS pretty well, and I think it might be a jquery conflict perhaps? 
I've tested this on both mac and PC versions of Safari..

I'm stumped.. Thoughts?

Comment: try adding display:block on the li's

Comment: Tried that.. Still no luck.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i observed the same. There's a conflict in the older webkit version.

WebKit version  537.36 --> Works fine **(Chrome  27.0.1453.110 m)**

WebKit version  534.57.2 --> Going Nuttts!! **[Safari 5.1.7(Build 7534.57.2)]**

Thats a bug in older Webkit.

Works fine in Gecko browser's too (**Mozilla Firefox**), Hence its not Jquery bug i guess. Its something related to webkit version.

---

Meanwhile you can try alternative for drop down menus:

http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html

http://www.handy-html.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/create-a-simple-css-dropdown-menu.html

---

**To test your Webkit follow this http://browserspy.dk/webkit.php**

Answer (score 1):

Well, managed to solve the issue.

Thanks to your help Nirus I did a bit more searching based on the weird webkit rendering issue.

I added the following to my navigation ID:

## navigation * {-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}

This did the trick!

Comment: @e2tango What is navigation ID ? Where is it located ? Pls help me, I'm having the same issue....